# Reading JSON & CSV of same format through AWS Athena Stored in S3

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am having the different data formats in my S3 folder inside bucket -

[image: Folder inside AWS S3 Bucket]

Table created which has the same columns for all the CSV, JSON & gz format files.

[image: Table in AWS Athena]

Now i am querying the data from Athena through the query -

```
SELECT *
FROM test2
WHERE readtime >= '2016-10-12'
  AND readtime <  '2016-10-24'
ORDER BY readtime
```

I am able to get the data from CSV and GZ file formats but not from the JSON files. 
Should I have to use the different format for querying the JSON files ?
and 
Can i use the same table to Query the JSON files which i have used for CSV files ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to create a different table on top of JSON file which will use JsonSerDe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per Tanveer's answer, you need to create a separate table for the JSON. But with a recently announced feature called Federated Queries (that's, at the time of writing this, in preview in `us-east-1`), you should be able to achieve querying both tables with the same query. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/writing-federated-queries.html